# Vue3 Prop passing to data item to be able to manipulate values, not modelling data item actually, why?

Tags: vuejs3

I am using **vue3** and wonder how to pass data the correct way.

My Component structure is one table (items loaded via pinia store): `XTableComponent`
The `XTableComponent` has a child: `XModalComponent`. In the rendered table I have a button in each row. `@click` on that stores the current item in a data item

`XTableComponent`:

```html
<template>
   ...that mentioned table in each line a button with @click and the item in the iteration as param
   <x-model-component v-if="currentItem" :item="currentItem ref="x-modal"></x-modal-component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data: () => {
      return {
        currentItem: {},
        itemListStore: useItemListStore()
      }
   },
   computed: {
      itemList() {
         return this.itemListStore.list
      }
   methods: {
     showModal(item){
         this.currentItem = item
         this.$refs['x-modal'].show()
     }
   }

}
</script>
```

My Child component looks a bit like this:

`XModalComponent`:

```html
<template>
 ....
<input v-model:value="innerItem.something" type="text">
<button @click="save">save</button>

</template>
<script>
export default {
   props: {
      item: Object
   },
   data: () => {
      return {
         innerItem: {}
      }
    }
   mounted() {
      this.innerItem = item
   },
   methods: {
      save() {
         console.log(this.innerItem) //this does not show the manipulated value of `something`
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Now, if I manipulate the input in my child component, and trigger a click event, the value does not get changed on my data item ...

what did I get wrong in vue3 with reactiveness, proxeis and passing props?

*p.s. my code is kind of pseude code here, so please be fair with me on typos, or obvious parts
that are missing*

*p.p.s. I am used to vue2 quite well, so maybe I mix concepts. please tell me that too.*

*p.p.p.s. my table renders correctly, the modal looks fine. i double checked all names and typos.*

Comment: I think you put `innerItem.something` into the input, but you don't write back (`:value="innerItem.something"` instead of `v-model="innerItem.something"`), so it never changes. Might be just an issue with the pseudo code though, or me missing something

Comment: Oh @MoritzRingler I had a closer look to that attribute. I used actually `v-model:value`. now using `v-model` only it is working. can you add an answer (I will update the pseudo code as well) and add some info, why this is (i.e.: https://vanoneang.github.io/article/v-model-in-vue3.html#recap-the-v-model-directive)

Comment: or maybe this link: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as we figured out, the problem came from the way `innerItem.something` was bound to the input, and some confusion around the `v-model` directive.

As a recap, the `v-model` directive is short-hand for setting a prop on a component and listening to an event which updates the value.

In Vue 2, that was:

```html
<child-component
  :value="myValue"
  @input="(nevValue) => myValue = newValue"
/>
```

which is equivalent to

```html
<child-component v-model="myValue"/>
```

and it allows a variable to be changed by parent as well as child ("two-way binding"). Note that property name and event matches that of a HTML input element (the "value" attribute and the "input" event), probably because it represents the most familiar case, where a value is bound to an input:

```html
<input type="text" v-model="myText"/>
```

However, to allow for multiple two-way bindings on a component, Vue 2 also introduced a second way, which allows to bind to any of the child components props, not just "value". This is the `.sync` modifier:

```html
<child-component :childComponentProp.sync="myVar"/>
```

which is equivalent to:

```html
<child-component
  :childComponentProp="myVar"
  @update:childComponentProp="(newValue) => myVar = newValue"
/>
```

In Vue 3, they decided to unify the two, dropping `.sync` and instead allowing to pass a prop name to `v-model` similar to how slot names are passed to the `v-slot` directive, i.e. `v-model:childComponentProp="myVar"`, and similar as `v-slot` alone is equivalent to `v-slot:default`, `v-model` alone is equivalent to `v-model:modelValue`. So it is equivalent to:

```html
<my-component
  :modelValue="myValue"
  @update:modelValue="(nevValue) => myValue = newValue"
/>
```

But the above only applies for Vue components. When using `v-model` on an HTML input element, it sill behaves like in Vue 2 and binds to the "value" attribute and the "input" event. It is still equivalent to:

```html
<input :value="myValue" @input="(nevValue) => myValue = nevValue"/>
```

**However**, that behavior is a special case of plain `v-model` (i.e. without a prop name). And I think this is where the confusion comes from.

Using `v-model:value` explicitly binds to the `@update:value` event, i.e. this

```html
<input v-model:value="innerItem.something" type="text">
```

is equivalent to:

```html
<input type="text"
  :value="innerItem.something"
  @update:value="(newValue) => innerItem.something = newValue" 
/>
```

but that event is not sent by a plain HTML element.

So long long story short, you have to use `v-model=` instead of `v-model:value=` when binding to a native input element.

Does that make sense? Hope it helps.